# Winforms application server communication

Tags: c#, winforms, domain-driven-design, communication

I am building a Winforms client that needs to communicate with a backend. This backend is build using Nhibernate (with a VERY rich domain model) , message queuing and other.

Now i do know about communicating over the internet ( mostly mq stuff) but i am at total loss as to how to let my Client Winforms App talk to the Application server to call the services.

What is the best way to do this ? I've read all about Nhibernte , DDD, WCF, remoting etc, but i just don't see how to do this the right way? How to design the services ( since the model is so extended, it would be a VERY chatty interface vs a VERY chunky interface)

So Basically: What is the best way to let a winforms app talk with the backend ( layering) and are there any good examples as to how to implement this ( including all layers because most examples stop at the Service Boundry :s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I liked the approach described in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796225.aspx) by Ayende, though have not tried it myself.

Worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

I would use WCF and several interfaces to define the services which is used to access the backend.

**Application.BusinessLayer**

Defines all WCF interfaces + domain entities. Used by the winform and backend.

A interface can look like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public inteface IUserService
{
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<User> Find(string searchWord);
}
```

That's all you need to define a WCF service.

**Application.Service**

Your backend. Implements all interfaces.

You can either configure WCF using the config file or by code. The WCF services can either run inside a ASP.Net application or a ServiceHost.

**Application.WinClient**

You winform application.

You can add a service reference if your application to your webservice if you host your WCF services in asp.net. Else you use ChannelFactory to create your service proxies.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally like to go for lean REST+JSON using ASP.NET MVC but the safest bet is WCF. There are tons of examples here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35ec8682-d5fd-4bc3-a51a-d8ad115a8792&displaylang=en

In terms of desiging the interface, break down the calls to the granular functionalities.

Comment: So you get something like: client <-> View <-> Model/Controller <-> WCF Service <-> Services <-> Model/Repository ?

Comment: Yes, I would say so. Other alternative is client <-> View <-> Model/Controller <-JSON+REST-> ASP.NET MVC <-> Services <-> Model/Repository

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the RPC (Remote Procedure Call) provided by WCF, you can also consider
to have your backend implemented as a service communicating via messages.
You can design such service to communicate one-way and/or request-response.
To implement the communication between applications via messages, you can consider to use **Eneter Messaging Framework**. It is lightweight and your applications can communicate based on NamedPipes, Tcp or Http.
If you are interested, you can get more technical info [here](http://www.eneter.net/OnlineHelp/EneterMessagingFramework/Index.html).
Or more examples you can find on *eneter.blogspot.com* and the framework can be downloaded from *www.eneter.net*.